# How to Draw a continuous line on touch path in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I tried using pixmap , but every time i draw a path and increaase drag speed , it shows space betweeen two pixmap circles.

I also tried by saving touch points in an array and drawind all the points by shaperenderer but same thing happened.

**I need to draw a smooth line like in  some image editor apps.**

Right now using this method.

```
    while (cIter.hasNext()) {
        penpoint = cIter.next();
        shapeRenderer.circle(penpoint.getPosition().x,
                penpoint.getPosition().y, 3);
    }
```

but it shows like this.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/pushbullet-uploads/ujCRdpmszeu-lp4uLBpI5MftwHBvmk58QP4w4mrzfkJx/Screenshot_2014-12-14-15-23-41.png

Comment: You get mouse position events at approx 60Hz, so even if you are perfect in converting these points to a line you will have gaps in the path... so I would connect the points as a line and also consider a kind of smoothing.

Answer (score 3):

do not know if this is what you want, but maybe you can use it for whatever you want to do, hope it helps.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Path-interface-%26-Splines
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/PathTest.java

P.S:maybe you can look on Beizer curves
https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=ssl#q=http://devmag.org.za+/2011/04/05+/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/